# rich:hotKey for Form Submission?

Tags: html, forms, jsf, richfaces, hotkeys

I've got a login form that looks something like this, using RichFaces and Seam:

```
<h:form id="loginForm">
   <h:outputLabel value="Username" />
   <h:inputText value="#{identity.credentials.username}" />
   <h:outputLabel value="Password" />
   <h:inputText value="#{identity.credentials.password}" />

   <h:commandLink action="#{identity.login()}" value="Login" />
</h:form>
```

I'd like to be able to allow the user to hit 'enter' and automatically submit the form to login.  I've tried using Richfaces' `<rich:hotKey />` feature, but I think I'm doing something wrong.  The code I've put in looks like this:

```
<rich:hotKey key="return"
   handler="#{rich:element('loginForm')}.submit()" />
```

However, when I hit enter inside the form, nothing happens.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those still struggling with this issue, I've finally gotten something that works.  My code now looks like this:

```
<h:form id="loginForm">
   <h:outputLabel value="Username" />
   <h:inputText value="#{identity.credentials.username}" />
   <h:outputLabel value="Password" />
   <h:inputText value="#{identity.credentials.password}" />

   <h:commandLink action="#{identity.login()}" value="Login" />
   <rich:hotKey key="return"
             handler="#{rich:element('loginForm')}.submit()" 
             selector="#loginForm"/>

</h:form>
```

You can also use a more specific selector so that an enter press only submits the form when the focus is on one of the form fields.  Either way, this FINALLY solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use selector property. Something like,

```
<rich:hotKey key="return"
             handler="#{rich:element('loginForm')}.submit()" 
             selector="#loginForm"/>
```

Also, instead of submitting the form, you should click submit button. Something like,

```
<rich:hotKey key="return"
             handler="#{rich:element('loginButton')}.click()" 
             selector="#loginForm"/>
```

Comment: If you notice, I'm not using a button for my submit.  Rather, it's a command link.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: h:commandlink produces a <a onclick=".."/> html element with an onclick method. So i don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: Hmmm...still not working.  And, I see the following error message in the Firefox error console when the page loads: 

Error: jQuery.hotkeys is undefined

Source File: http://localhost:8080/dw/a4j/g/3_3_3.Final/org/richfaces/ui.pack.js

Line: 12158

Comment: To use jquery in your pages you need to include it in your page. Something like <a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>. Have you added this?

Comment: it seems like jquery is not loaded. You should check it with firebug or with another tool if jquery is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. I hope you can get some idea..

```
 <body>
        <h:form id="loginForm">

            <h:outputLabel value="Username : " />
            <h:inputText id="userNameId" value="#{Login.username}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Password : " />
            <h:inputText id="passwordId" value="#{Login.password}" />

            <a4j:commandButton id="loginButton" action="#{Login.loginButton}" value="Login" focus="button"/>

            <rich:hotKey key="return"
                         selector="#userNameId"
                         handler="#{rich:element('loginForm:loginButton')}.click();
                         event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();
                         return false;"/>

            <rich:hotKey key="return"
                         selector="#passwordId"
                         handler="#{rich:element('loginForm:loginButton')}.click();
                         event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();
                         return false;"/>
        </h:form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Your code works great if I'm using <a4j:commandButton /> or <h:commandButton />.  However, for styling purposes I'm using an <h:commandLink /> as my submit "button".  Is there any way to get <rich:hotKey /> to work with a commandLink instead of a commandButton?